# Closing down HTTP/2 connections to IIS programmatically

Tags: c#, sockets, iis, http2, azure-load-balancer

Is there a simple way to close HTTP/2 connection to IIS gracefully? For http/1.1 we just change the header to Connection: Close or recycle the app pool and this drops all the keep-alive http connections but we cant find a way for http/2.

The scenerio. We have a server in a farm that we are trying to gracefully shutdown behind a basic azure load balancer. We have a load balancer probe port that once closed traffic stops being directed to the server. This all works but http/2 connections remain connected and sending requests. Keep-Alive is disabled. Stopping or recycling the app pool leaves the connection connected.

We can write a script to forceabley terminate the socket prior to shutdown but I am guessing if its in mid request we have a client side problem or is the HTTP/2 protocol smart enough to handle this? Try it in Chrome worked without issue but it wasnt during say a longer running request.

We can restart IIS but we might as well shutdown the server at this point.

Is there anyway via http.sys/http api to disconnect these connections?

Comment: This is not really my forte, however can you send them all a goaway frame perhaps?

Comment: Totally considered this but just wasnt sure if it was even possible to send a goaway frame when I have no access to the socket (as its managed by the system)

Comment: How did you end up solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

If Connection: close is added to headers for a HTTP/2 stream, that in no way should affect the state of the HTTP/2 session. If the server is shutting down, the HTTP/2 implementation stops all HTTP/2 sessions.

According to Microsoft documentation we can use **reset**.

**Reset allows for the server to reset a HTTP/2 request with a specified error code. A reset request is considered aborted.**

```
var resetFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResetFeature>();
resetFeature.Reset(errorCode: 2);
```

For information about "Use ASP.NET Core with HTTP/2 on IIS", you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/protocols?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Thanks for that.. I was aware of the connection: close header. I thought I was onto a winner until I realized its not http/2 supported. Unfortuantely in this scenerio the management of the server happens outside of the application and its mostly .net framework stuff so if we were to find a .net framework solution to this, it would be a very expensive roll out. Trying to find a way of doing it from a core/central point.

Comment: We can reset the HTTP/2 request using code.